# Connecting to oracle 11g on Red hat linux from windows server using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, linux, oracle, sql-server-2008-r2

We have our application developed and tested with sql server 2008r2 using ASP.NET on windows server.  Now we have a requirement to move the database from windows to oracle on red hat linux.

We haven't yet setup the infrastructure to test the same.  I would like to know in the meantime if anyone has successfully done this kind of thing. Pointers to any resources will be a great advantage.

Is changing the connection string the only thing that needs to be done or are there any specific configuration in Linux to allow this?

I will verify this once I get the environment ready, but as a headstart if anyone has any similar experience, do share.

Thanks in advance.

P.S:  For migration of  table structure, storedprocedures etc to oracle we will be using the Sql Developer tool.

Comment: From a connectivity perspective the connectionString change should be fine. Are you using any ORM to access database?

Comment: No ORM, we have a datalayer which is provider agnostic and can plug in any provider as required.

Comment: Then I don't see any major issues o ce the connectivity is verified, given the data access layer is already established to be db agnostic.

Comment: Thanks.. got the environment, will try out and post of possible issues  if i encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my question,because, migration to oracle is not that straight forward, but there are some tips that may help anyone migrate to oracle on windows or linux with less headache.

The first thing the Sql developer tool does a good job of migrating sqlserver schema and data to oracle including storedprocedures, constraints, triggers etc.

It also does a good job of datatype mapping and provides option to remap datatype if required.

Some caveats and precautions.

1. Oracle has a limitation on the length of stored procedure names of about 30 characters.  This is the area you need to resort to some manual renaming as when migration SP's or identifiers whose name is greater than 30 characters may get truncated.
2. The other common issue that you may face is respect to date insertion and formatting.  You can use the following snippet to avoid the headache.  The common error will be "Not a valid month."

OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
conn.Open();
OracleGlobalization session = conn.GetSessionInfo();
session.DateFormat = "DD.MM.RR";  // change the format as required here
conn.SetSessionInfo(session);

3. The most annoying error would be well character to numeric conversion when inserting or updating data or related error.

The issue here is when you add parameters to command object for sql provider, the binding happens by name, but forOracle.DataAccess the default binding is by position.  Here's the post that saved me lot of headache.
[ODP .NET Parameter problem with uint datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098668/odp-net-parameter-problem-with-uint-datatype)

What you can do is set the  command.BindByName = true;

4. When migrating SP's that returns data, oracle creates an out parameter ref cursor.  This needs to be taken care of while constructing command parameters.

For e.g. 
  OracleParameter refp = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("cv_1",   OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);

command.Parameters.Add(refp);

5. Also the sqlserver requires parameters to SP be prefixed with "@" and oracle doesn't. This can be easily taken care of in your data layer.
6. Also since there is no bit datatype in Oracle, number(1) works fine.  You may need to convert your bool to numeric, if required.

Hope this helps someone avoid a migration headaches.  I will post more issues if I encounter.